# ecobee API thermostat request (json) using bash and curl

Tags: bash, curl, ecobee-api

I'm writing a bash script to interface with my ecobee (query info and change settings).  I have the authorization all worked out (access token and refresh token) and am now trying to request info from the ecobee. This json parameter list is dynamically created. None of the curl examples in the Developers API Doc seem to work.

I've tried assigning the json to a variable (`?json="$selection"`) and to a file (`?json=@"$location"`).  My latest attempt (hard coding the json and escaping the braces) of the curl is as follows:

```
response=$(curl -s "https://api.ecobee.com/1/thermostat?json=\{"selection":\{"selectionType":"registered","selectionMatch":null,"includeRuntime":true,"includeSettings":true/}/}" -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token")
```

and I received a null response `declare -- response=""`

If I have curl read from a file:
`{"selection":{"selectionType":"registered","selectionMatch":null,"includeRuntime":true,"includeSettings":true}}`

then I receive:

```
response='{
  "status": {
    "code": 4,
    "message": "Serialization error. Malformed json. Check your request and parameters are valid."
  }
}'
```

Which I assuming it' an escape issue?

Can anyone offer any insight?  Again, I thought this would be the easy part.  I'm using jq to build my request json.  Other alternatives to curl that can better deal with json?  I'm limited to bash (which is what I know)

Thanks

Comment: You say you're composing the JSON query using jq. Try adding the `@uri` filter and the `-r` option, then use the output as inline URI parameter. For your example I get `%7B%22selection%22%3A%7B%22selectionType%22%3A%22registered%22%2C%22selectionMatch%22%3Anull%2C%22includeRuntime%22%3Atrue%2C%22includeSettings%22%3Atrue%7D%7D`. May be worth a try.

Comment: WOW!  That worked! "?json=$(jq -r '@uri' ~/etc/ecobee.selection)". Please post this as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate (arbitrary) data into a URL (or URI in general) you need to prepare it using [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) first.

As you have mentioned to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to compose that data, you could add `@uri` to your jq filter to perform the encoding, and use the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) option to then output it properly.

For example, `jq -r '@uri'` applied to your JSON

```json
{
  "selection": {
    "selectionType": "registered",
    "selectionMatch": null,
    "includeRuntime": true,
    "includeSettings": true
  }
}
```

would [output](https://jqplay.org/s/Ci7KsAkK3q)

```
%7B%22selection%22%3A%7B%22selectionType%22%3A%22registered%22%2C%22selectionMatch%22%3Anull%2C%22includeRuntime%22%3Atrue%2C%22includeSettings%22%3Atrue%7D%7D
```

which you can use within the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) `?json=…`.

Comment: I don't know ecobee at all, but chances are there's also another, more comfortable way to feed it with your JSON file (e.g. using [`POST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) instead of `GET` as request method), as the total length of the query string is limited and your JSON might grow over time.

Comment: Thanks again for the very detailed answer. Was banging my head on this for most of the weekend

Comment: I found Ecobee’s API doc limited with Curl samples that don’t seem to work.